# My laptop (using Ubuntu) is not restarting after I hit restart and a few power off and on attempts as well. Its only showing codes and I cannot figure

Tags: reboot, restore

I was casually using my laptop and the windows suddenly won't open so I clicked restart and all I see now are codes.and its telling us to format all the existing files and we don't know how to restore our data. This is an image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zb3E.jpg)

Comment: I see only kernel boot messages; but you've provided no OS/release details (if it's Ubuntu; is it a Ubuntu Core system?, Ubuntu Server system? Ubuntu Desktop system?  what release of said system?) nor when you restarted did you do so safely (ie. cleanly shutdown via command/instruction/SysRq etc) or not.  If not did you check file-systems (ie. `fsck` as appropriate for your unstated OS/release/fs) as if errors were detected/fixed you'd likely have normal boot/operation restored - but being specific with details helps us to help you.

Comment: Ubuntu desktop system. And I long pressed the power button and then hit restart.